# getting duplicate navigation options at the top

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am showing a list of services on my page. I am using react-navigation. Somehow, I see two navigation bar on the top of my phone. Below is the image:

[image]

I just want the top most navigation bar. I don't want the second one. I looked at my code several times, but could not find the error. I am not sure what am I doing wrong that I am seeing duplicate navigation bar. Below is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ListView, ActivityIndicator, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducers from '../reducers/ServiceReducer';
import ServiceItem from './ServiceItem';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';
import ServiceDetail from './ServiceDetail';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import ServiceListDetails from './ServiceListDetails' ;

class AutoCompActivity extends Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {

      // Default Value of this State.
      Loading_Activity_Indicator: true,
      text:'',
      selected_topic_id: -1,

    }
    this.arrayholder=[];
  }
 componentDidMount() {

    const data = require('../reducers/services.json')



        let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.setState({
          Loading_Activity_Indicator: false,
          dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data),
        }, function() {

          // In this block you can do something with new state.
          this.arrayholder = data ;
        });


  }


  SearchFilterFunction(text){

    const newData = this.arrayholder.filter(function(item){
        const itemData = item.ser.toUpperCase()
        const textData = text.toUpperCase()
        return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1
    })
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newData),
        text: text
    })
}

ListViewItemSeparator = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        height: .5,
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "#000",
      }}
    />
  );
}
clickedItemText( clickedItem )
    {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Item', { item: clickedItem ,  navigationOptions:{header:null}}   );
    }


  static navigationOptions =
    {

     title: 'testing'

    };

render()
{
  // this is my render code. I can put the render code if someone wants to see it.
}


export default MyNewProject=   StackNavigator(
{
  First:   {screen: AutoCompActivity},
  Item: {screen: ServiceListDetails, navigationOptions:{header:null}},

}
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it's tough to tell what's going on here. Where you have this:

```
static navigationOptions =
{

 title: 'testing'

};
```

try changing it to this:

```
static navigationOptions =
{

 header: null,

};
```

There are a couple places you can disable or define the header from. One is in the component itself, and one is in the second parameter of `StackNavigator()`.

For example, you could have this:

```
export default MyNewProject = StackNavigator(
  {
    First:   {screen: AutoCompActivity},
    Item: {screen: ServiceListDetails},
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    }
  }
)
```

Or you could have this:

```
class AutoCompActivity extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I was just reading this article here last night. You may find it helpful in seeing some different aspects you aren't using yourself currently: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-a-custom-header-and-custom-bottom-tab-bar-for-react-native-with-react-navigation-969a5d3cabb1

Based on what I see here, try `header: null` in the second parameter Object of StackNavigator. I have a feeling one of the headers will go away but for that whole stack. It's really confusing. I sometimes hate it myself, but it is good for supporting composition once you find a pattern you like.

My wording here might be confusing. I'm saying `null` them all out until you can gain a handle on it.

Comment: Header:null will work. As you cans see in my original post that I have one Header:null. Problem is as soon as I do Header:null, both the headers disappear. I want one header to be there.

Comment: I will see about radically altering my answer to your question and/or writing a Medium article with details about how to solve this particular challenge because I think it involves a bit of composition and examination of a few individual pieces, and we also have to think about memory usage because we don't want the navigation stack getting more than 15 screens on it any any given time at the risk of a general slow-down. A switchNavigator is good for this, and guides us in a particular direction.

Comment: And by individual pieces, I mean a top nav bar that might be different depending what screen your on and back button requirements, and we might have a bottom nav bar that is pretty static, but we need to be able to pass data from screens to headers and observe the `activeRoute`. You can render the header from any switch or stack navigator, or screen, and you could maximally or minimally rely on `react-navigation` to handle rendering needs. There are many confusing options available. I'm going to try to address these factors.

Comment: We also have to usually think about authentication and security. I think I can produce an answer that shows us some of the higher-level data flow channels and then a person can modify the pattern to suit an app, such as maybe a sidebar or drawer instead of a bottom nav bar.

Comment: I am still having issues. Please let me know if you posted the answer somewhere